# macでlocalhostに繋ごうとするとエラーになる。

Tags: macos

Macでローカルにアクセスしようとすると以下のエラーになります。

```
http://localhost
http://172.0.0.1
```

以下エラーになります。

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

ちなみにdocker周りのファイル、設定は全て削除しています。
また以下のコマンドで確かめてみたのですが、通常通りでした。

```
dig localhost +short
#172.0.0.1
```

何か設定ファイルが変わってしまっているのでしょうか。何を修正すればいいかわからず、教えてほしいです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: エラーが無ければどのような結果になることを期待していますか？ 「Docker 関連の設定は削除した」ということは以前は使っていた / 今は不要、ということでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、デフォルトてきなものがあるのかと勘違いしてました。失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` の場合を含め、ネットワーク越しで何かにアクセスする場合には宛先側で応答するプログラム (いわゆるサーバ) が動作している必要があります。

エラーに出ている "localhost port 80" というのは HTTP でアクセスしようとしていますから、mac上で予め webサーバが起動している必要がありますし、特にwebサーバは動作させていないのであれば "応答が無い" のは正常な結果です。

Comment: なるほどご教授いただきありがとうございます。